# VS code rectangle block cursor not changing to line

Tags: visual-studio-code, cursor

[image: VS Code Rectangle cursor not going away]

- Settings: Cursor Style = "Line"
- Disabled font related extensions
- Restarted VS code but the issue is not going away
- With [Fn + Insert] key, it changes rectangle to line temporarily, but returning back to rectangle shape when moving to next line

Please help me with what needs to be done here to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `editor.cursorWidth` setting.  When you have the cursor style set to line, this setting can change the size of it, giving the appearance of a block:

[image: editor cursor width setting]

The default is 0, so revert it back to that if it isn't.